# Need to call a page on the code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `script` like this.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "uploaded", "$(document).ready(function(){$('#successmsg').dialog('open');});", true);
```

In place of `#successmsg` I want to call an aspx page. So what can I do to call that.

Also suggest if there is any alternate method related to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this code call just from code behind

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour: This is already called from code-behind, I need to call the aspx page using this script only.

Comment: you called it under which event

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour: It is called under `Button_Click` event on code behind

Comment: You cant because it run at server side do post back you need to do it in Clint side

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour: How can we do it on client side, do let me know. Will apply that and see whether it suits my requirement or not

Comment: if you have team viewer I can access and see how can I help you coz I don't know what is your situation